# How to handle unknown Vendors for mac-vendor-lookup

Tags: python-3.x, mac-address

I would like to create a dict based on MAC addresses and vendor, using the `mac-vendor-lookup` library. My code:

```
dicts = {}
for index, value in mac_series.items():
    try:
        vendor = mac.lookup(value)
    except KeyError as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        vendor = "UNKNOWN"
    dicts[value] = vendor
```

This works fine, because I handle KeyErrors in the try/except. However I'd like to know why I get a KeyError in the first place, when the Mac addresses all follow a certain format. So I get mostly vendors coming back, but sometimes the occasional "UNKNOWN". Is this an issue with an outdated lookup (despite using the latest pip package)?

Comment: What is `mac_series`? Have you tried printing out the `value` when you get a `KeyError` to see what MACs are causing the error? If so, can you share some of them?

Answer (score 0):

As per the library, you will need to update the vendors list often using the following code

```
mac.update_vendors()  # <- This can take a few seconds for the download
```

Also sometimes the Mac address you are trying to lookup for is a fake one, so there will be no results for it, better paste the mac address you are trying with.

---

Another alternative you can download [mac address lookup](https://devtools360.com/en/macaddress/vendorMacs.xml) XML file and build your own lookup code on top of it, but you will need to update it regularly.